# How to load hiveContext in Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am new to zeppelin notebook. But i noticed one thing that unlike spark-shell hiveContext is not automatically created in zeppelin when i start the notebook.

And when i tried to manually load the hiveContext in zeppelin like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:204)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive(HiveContext.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.setConf(HiveContext.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.defaultOverrides(HiveContext.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
```

I think the error means that the previous metastore_db is not allowing to override the new one.

I am using spark 1.6.1

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check your metastore_db permission...
then you test by  on REPL Mode..
then you have to move zeppelin.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to connect Hive from shell. I just wanted you to check if Hive is installed properly because I had a similar issue some times back. Also try to connect Hive from Scala shell. If it works, then it should work from Zeppelin.

Comment: I dont have hive installed.. Do i really need hive to use hiveContext in zeppelin?

Comment: Yes you need to install the Hive.

Answer (score 0):

try creating the HIVE context as follows :

PYSPARK CODE.

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf()

hiveContext = HiveContext(sc)

Hope it Helps.

Regards,

Neeraj

Comment: bhadnani Hi, I did the exact same thing in scala but got this error